Session management in Flask-SQLAlchemy-Lite
I'm moving from vanilla SQLAlchemy to Flask-SQLAlchemy-Lite.
What is the best practice for session management?  Can I still do something like this:
    with db.session as session, session.begin():

if I want the block to automatically commit?


Can I still do something like this:

Yes, that appears to work just fine.
with app.app_context():
    Base.metadata.create_all(db.engine)

    db.engine.echo = True

    db.session.add(User(username="example", rev=0))
    db.session.commit()
    """
INSERT INTO user (username, rev) VALUES (?, ?)
[generated in 0.00080s] ('example', 0)
COMMIT
    """

    with db.session as sess, sess.begin():
        u = sess.get(User, 1)
        u.rev += 1
        
    """
UPDATE user SET rev=? WHERE user.id = ?
[generated in 0.00083s] (1, 1)
COMMIT
    """


Thanks, I notice in your responses that you included the SQL code as comments within the Python code.  Do you do that manually or is there some tool that does that

I just copy and paste them in.

You will need to use autocommit=False in sessionmaker. So it will be like this:
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, bind=engine)

Then you will be able to use session.commit() to commit changes when it is required.
To use session you can can create a method like this:
@contextmanager
def session_scope() -> Session:
    if SessionLocal is not None:
        session = SessionLocal()
        try:
            yield session
            session.commit()
        except Exception:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()

and use it like this:
with session_scope() as session:

But you can also directly use SessionLocal in the code without contextmanagers but remember to close it once you are done.
EDIT: Seems that sqlaclhemy 2.0 doesn't support autocommit=True.

Did you mean autoflush=False ?

If you want the block an automatically commit you will need use autocommit=False to prevent autocommiting at the end of session. autoflush=False will block auto flush during a session but it is required to do commit() at end to save changes.

but this says "the “autocommit” keyword is present for backwards compatibility but must remain at its default value of False."

My point is that I do want it to commit at the end of the session block.  Why would I want autocommit=False ?  I thought that's what session.begin() does.  It automatically comments at the end of the context, right?

Yes session.begin() automatically will commit changes by the end of transaction. But I personally prefer to control when a commit is done.
